# Multiple (File.java:123) type links per line in console output

Tags: intellij-idea

I have my own logger that includes part of a stack trace for each logging statement like this:

2015-03-27 23:12:56,582 INFO something something something (Abc.java:123) (Abc.java:201) (Test.java:99)

Eclipse would turn each parenthesis file/line combination into a clickable link. But IDEA only makes the last one clickable.
I can't find an option to turn the other ones into links. If it there is not out-of-the-box option to enable this behavior, is it feasible to easily implement a plug in for it? Perhaps someone knows of an existing plugin? I can imagine that for some languages some people had the need to make it clickable. I'm seeing the ConsoleURL plugin, which could be a starting point.

What's the easiest route to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question. I found a plugin called "Awesome Console", that's in the included list in IDEA. It automagically made the other file:line combinations clickable.